# Redirect to errors

Tags: support, questions, migration

On our front page, we have now the following question:

[Graph having diameter k times the average distance [closed]](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/graph-having-diameter-k-times-the-average-distance-closed)

If you click on the link, you are redirected to a "Page Not Found" error message at math.stackexchange.com.

Perhaps this is related to a question that was first migrated and then deleted, but the end result is certainly confusing. And it bothers me a bit: a question has been closed, but I cannot read the question or the reason why it was closed.

Comment: I agree that it is confusing.  For this instance alone, you can read the close reason at [http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/graph-having-diameter-k-times-the-average-distance?noredirect=1](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/graph-having-diameter-k-times-the-average-distance?noredirect=1).

Comment: Tsuyoshi's link doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a user who is very confused.

That "question" has now been deleted from every site it appeared on, so.. not sure what conclusions to draw here other than, sometimes users do dumb things.

Comment: Good UI does not leave users confused.  You are saying that the UI of your website is not good.  Well, I am happy that we have the same conclusion.